# How to set building SDK in Android Studio 1.0?

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to import an eclipse project to Android studio 1.0.

First I get this message:

```
Error:failed to find target android-19 : ...\Android\sdk
```

Install missing platform(s) and sync project

But I don't want to install SDK 19, so I use F4 key on module to open settings, but then I get:

```
Error:(18) A problem occurred evaluating root project '2TVSSA-Library'.
Could not find method android() for arguments [build_9n8e326ws1pb1ogxq6eh7vjg0$_run_closure3@4815ddf5] on root project '2TVSSA-Library'.
```

I just downloaded Android Studio 1.0, but it tells me android() is missed? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was an auto-created or imported module in the project. I can't modify the building SDK in root, since it does not have `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`.

Change sub-module's `build.gradle`'s android->compleSdkVersion solved the problem.